# Intel's DftiComputeForward() not working correctly

Tags: c, fft, intel-mkl

I am facing an issue with DftiComputeForward(); The issue is when I am using the DftiComputeForward in the below format: status = DftiComputeForward(*dftiH, x, y); Instead of adding the computed value to "y", it is adding it in "x", and keeping the y as empty. I also tried the below format: status = DftiComputeForward(*dftiH, y); In this case also the "y" is empty. I did validate the descriptor handle by getting the size out of it, and the value that it returned was correct. Any ideas on why DftiComputeForward() could behave like this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did find the issue with this one. It was in the creation of the descriptor handle dftiH. after creating the descriptor the code was setting value DFTI_INPLACE. This meant that the second parameter of "ComputeForward" will be treated as a variable that contains both in and out values. I have now set the value to DFTI_NOT_INPLACE. Things work fine :)
Link for details on this paramter:
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/onemkl-developer-reference-c/top/fourier-transform-functions/fft-functions/configuration-settings/dfti-placement.html#dfti-placement

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).